# How to get the saved value form my custom form field type in joomla?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I have created my custom form field for a module.However, it work will but when ever i get back to the module i don't know what is the previous value or the saved value, because i didn't make it selected there.

```
<?php
// Check to ensure this file is included in Joomla!
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

jimport('joomla.form.formfield');

class JFormFieldSlidercategory extends JFormField {

    protected $type = 'Slidercategory';

    // getLabel() left out

    public function getInput() {

                $db = JFactory::getDBO();
                $query = $db->getQuery(true);
                $query->select('id,title');
                $query->from('#__h2mslider_categories');
                $db->setQuery((string)$query);
                $messages = $db->loadObjectList();
                $options ='';


                if ($messages)
                {
                        foreach($messages as $message) 
                        {
                                $options .= '<option value="'.$message->id.'" >'.$message->title.'</option>';
                        }
                }


                $options = '<select id="'.$this->id.'" name="'.$this->name.'">'.
                       '<option value="0" >--select a category--</option>'.
                       $options.
                       '</select>';

                return $options ;


    }
}
```

I need the function that return me the saved value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get value using this-  `$this->value`

Or you can try this code for select box-

```
// No direct access to this file
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

// import the list field type
jimport('joomla.form.helper');
JFormHelper::loadFieldClass('list');

class JFormFieldSlidercategory extends JFormFieldList
{
    /**
     * The field type.
     *
     * @var     string
     */
    protected $type = 'Slidercategory';

    /**
     * Method to get a list of options for a list input.
     *
     * @return  array       An array of JHtml options.
     */
    protected function getOptions() 
    {
        $db = JFactory::getDBO();
            $query = $db->getQuery(true);
            $query->select('id,title');
            $query->from('#__h2mslider_categories');
            $db->setQuery((string)$query);
            $messages = $db->loadObjectList();

        $options = array();
        if ($messages)
        {
            foreach($messages as $message) 
            {
                $options[] = JHtml::_('select.option', $message->id, $message->title);
            }
        }

        $options = array_merge(parent::getOptions(), $options);     
        return $options;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks `$this->value` worked will with me.
the other code show error on `parent::getOptions()`, maybe I did i wrong 
(f)